# Why don't dictionaries include the most common meaning of the word "punt"?

Tags: dictionaries

Why don't dictionaries include what is, in my opinion, the most common meaning of the word "punt", which is to "(strategically) give up"

> They punted on the hard problem.

Neither Oxford's, nor M-W list this meaning. In fact, M-W lists ten different meanings, many of which I never encountered.

Comment: I've never heard it mean "give up". That sentence to me would imply that they took some speculative approach to solving the problem. What sources use it in the way you suggest?

Comment: In my English zone, the most common meaning (noun) is a flat boat used on a river, propelled and steered using a pole, other meanings include 'bet', and 'shove or push across'. So MaxB, your "opinion" is not valid everywhere.

Comment: But [American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/punt) has your meaning ("Football" definition). It's one of those words where context and region can impact meaning. To "take a punt" can mean to "give something a go" or "to dropkick a football". I always assumed the football meaning was that they were a long way from the goal and they dropkicked the ball hoping to get lucky, but apparently it really is just a drop kick.

Comment: I don't think of "punt" in this context as meaning to give up, but to postpone. (Similar to "kicking the can down the road.") I am surprised this meaning is not in the dictionary, but I think it is a metaphor based on the boating meaning: pushing the problem away.

Comment: "Punt", in normal use, does not mean to not do something entirely, but rather to delay (possibly indefinitely) any action -- kick the can down the road.

Comment: I've only ever heard Punt used to describe a boat (or propelling said boat), taking a chance (whether a bet, or a speculative attempt at something), or the action of kicking the ball down the field (specifically without it bouncing on the floor first). (and also an old form of currency that doesn't exist anymore). Never heard it used to delay or give up. (UK). Could you elaborate where you are from? I could believe the word might have an extra meaning in some places, but to be the most common meaning somewhere seems odd.

Comment: I've heard *punt* used not to delay per se, but to pass a problem onto somebody else. As in *I decided to punt it to somebody else.* Or *they punted it back and forth.* It has the same effect of delaying a solution (because it's not being dealt with directly) but it doesn't mean delay in an explicit sense,.

Comment: There is an American expression "drop back ten and punt" which refers to the act, in American football, of "punting" the ball.  Though there are exceptions, this tactic is mostly used when it's 4th down and long yards, so the players are hoping for a minor miracle where they can recover the ball vs losing it to the other team.  I've always assumed that "punting", in the business sense, referred to this idiom.  However, since this tactic is mostly used in difficult situations where there are few other option, I suppose many people interpret it as simply "giving up".

Comment: @JasonBassford - That would be the difference between US and UK "football".  Likely the term "punt" has different meanings on opposite sides of the pond.